# Naming unknown services or define a gateway in istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kiali, gloo

I'm kind of stuck here we're currently taking steps to move our monolith into microservices on Kubernetes.
We use the following:

- Kubesphere 3.0
- Istiod 16.10
- Gloo Latest.

As you can see the traffic is known to flow from the **gloo** API gateway but I want it to be known instead of the unknown I've tried some google searches but couldn't find anything!

[example!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TYAo.png)

Comment: Not sure, gloo API gateway is supposed to be well integrated with istio, but perhaps this part is missing. That could be an issue in gloo. You could try to create an istio ingress-gateway, this would be a bit redundant, but that could "fix" the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response Joel!,

I've used ingress gateway it works fine but the reason we started using Gloo for our incoming traffic is things like OpenAPI/Swagger support. Currently there is no such thing in istio :(